# JaVers duplicates object snapshot versions in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, javers

Two java services work with the same mongo db.
Both share the same entity, which is distributed as a separate jar lib.
Both have Javers configuration and store snapshots to the same jv_snapshots.

The problem:

1. For example Service 1 updates entity "example" field and Javers saves shapshot with version 2
2. Then Service 2 updates the same field of the same entity and Javers saves shapshot with version 2 again. Why it is not 3 ?
3. As a result in jv_snapshots we have **two records with version 2 related to the same entity**.

Comment: Disabling cache did help.
For spring-boot app it is in property javers.snapshotsCacheSize=0
For mongo-templates approach - javers MongoRepository has costructor which gets cache size.